# How to embed VLC into a java project in eclipse

Tags: java, video, vlc

In my java project, I download a video from the website and want to play it by VLC. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is very late to answer, but it is to help others who are facing the same problem. You can excute it by using :

```
ProcessBuilder p=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe","new.avi");
p.start();
```

ProcessBuilder is used to create operating system processes, start() starts the process. This will play particular file in vlc.